# How do i get facebook comments and number of likes using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to access facebook comments using graph API Like below:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "113424589086090_113712022390680",
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "created_time": "2016-06-21T10:44:33+0000",
              "from": {
                "name": "Suneel Kumar",
                "id": "113424589086090"
              },
              "message": "nice photo4",
              "id": "113712022390680_113712149057334"
            },
            {
              "created_time": "2016-06-21T10:57:10+0000",
              "from": {
                "name": "Suneel Kumar",
                "id": "113424589086090"
              },
              "message": "ok",
              "id": "113712022390680_113724525722763"
            },
            {
              "created_time": "2016-06-21T10:57:15+0000",
              "from": {
                "name": "Suneel Kumar",
                "id": "113424589086090"
              },
              "message": "not bad",
              "id": "113712022390680_113724615722754"
            },
```

And This is the code ;

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?fields=posts%7Bcomments%7D&access_token=XXX"
```

How do I get comments and umber of likes.
I see something like this:
**/{object-id}/likes**

What is object-is here?

Answer (score 0):

`object-id` is the ID of the object, which can be a user, page, post, comment, etc.

In this case, to get the likes of this post, the `object-id` would be `113424589086090_113712022390680`.